# How to add headers in a CSV file in ASP.NET using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, csv, oledb

I need to add headers in my CSV Files. The problem is, every day the CSV files I am using in the program are changing. This is how my CSV File looks like:

```
1/29/2014 12:01AM        1834.854167
1/29/2014 12:02AM        1818.488333
1/29/2014 12:03AM        1802.1225
1/29/2014 12:04AM        1785.756667
1/29/2014 12:05AM        1769.390833
```

This is the code I am using:

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(CSVdirectory)
    Dim connString As String
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

    connString = (Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=") & BackUpDirectory) + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited'"

    conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()


    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + Q12014file + "]", conn)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    dt = New DataTable()

    da.Fill(dt)

    'Return

    conn.Close()
```

As you will probably notice, I don't have much liberty in querying since the column name always change every day. I would like to add headers in the columns of the CSV Files the code is reading. Please help.

Comment: Where is the code you use to generate the CSV?  That is where you will make the changes.  What do you want for header names?  The column names from the table?

Comment: hi Tim. I did not generate the CSV files. They already exists (our machine technicians only sends them to me every day). The column names from the table should be "TimeStamp" and "Pressure". Do you think we can add another row in the datatable instead?

Comment: Can you pls clarify? What does `GetDataTabletFromCSVFile` do? It seems you already have a DataTable?

Comment: The GetDataTabletFromCSVFile retrieves the data from a CSV file and copies it to a data table. The format in using that would be: Dim name As DataTable = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile("csv file path"). The Q12014file is the filename to be retrieved located in the csv file path. The OleDbCommand determines which data in the CSV file is to be retrieved.

Comment: @lulutanseco - I'm not following how column names matter in this situation.  You have a CSV file (actually it looks more like a tab-delimited file) with 2 pieces (columns, if you will) of data per line.  The select command (as currently written) will get all the columns - it's been a long day so I'm probably not connecting all the dots.  You can always access the columns by their ordinal rather than a name.

Comment: Actually, what I would like to do is to use WHERE and INSERT statements and I need column names for that. But you're right, I can use ordinal rather than name. So I would just go with that. Thanks